# Functions and continuity: constant functions

Tags: analysis, functions, continuity, solution-verification

Suppose that $g$ is a continuous function and that $g(x)=0$  $\forall x \in \mathbb{Q} $.  Prove that $g(x)=0$    $\forall$   $x$ in     $\mathbb{R} $.
So, assume that g is not equal to 0 for some a* in $\mathbb{R}$  \ $\mathbb{Q} $. 
We know that $g$ is continuous. So, assume that  c $\in$ $ \mathbb{Q} $. Set $ \epsilon $ = $ \lvert f(a^*) \rvert - \frac12 $. 
Hence, if $ \lvert a^*-c \rvert \lt \delta$, then $ \lvert f(a^*)-f(c) \rvert \lt \epsilon $.
However, $ \lvert f(a^*)-f(c) \rvert \lt \epsilon $ = $ \lvert f(a^*) \rvert \lt \epsilon $, since $f(c)=0$, as c $\in$ $ \mathbb{Q} $ . But this is a contradiction as 
$ \lvert f(a^*) \rvert \lt \epsilon =  \lvert f(a^*) \rvert - \frac12 . $
So, $ \lvert f(a^*)  \rvert \lt \lvert f(a^*) \rvert - \frac12 $, which is a contradiction which arose by assuming g is not equal to 0 for some a* $\mathbb{R}$  \ $\mathbb{Q} $. Hence, $g(x)=0 \forall x \in \mathbb{R} $.

Any mistakes, pointers or improvements for this proof?

Comment: You're on the right track. There is one small mistake and two notes you can make to make this prove super complete (though you might have been thinking about it and just omitted here).

1. The $\epsilon$ you pick must satisfy $\epsilon > 0$. For $\epsilon = |f(a*)| - \frac{1}{2}$, is this always true?
2. (It was an omission but it is not wrong) Where does $\delta$ come from?
3. (Another omission, a small mistake if you are being really picky) You picked some $c \in \mathbb{Q}$. Why does it satisfy the inequalities you state later? Does any $c \in \mathbb{Q}$ cut it?

Comment: Didn’t think about that! Thanks for pointing it out. For the epsilon part, what if we let epsilon to be the floor function of f(a*) and then the modulus of that? So no matter what f(a*) is, |f(a*)| < | floor(f(a*)) | will be a contradiction.

Comment: Also, I’m not sure what you mean by where does the delta come from. I normally think that you can let delta be anything because that should be the case for all delta, if this makes sense.

Comment: Another proof is that for any $x$ there are rationals $q_n \to x$ and since $g(x_n) = 0$ and $g$ is continuous we have $g(x) = 0$.